# Installing CUDA without gcc-4.3

Tags: cuda, debian, driver, gcc4.4

So I downloaded the latest Cuda (5.0.35) script to install Cuda on my desktop on which I have Debian (kernel 2.6.32).

When I ran the script though I get an error on the log which says:

The compiler used to compile the kernel (gcc-4.3) does not exactly match the current compiler (gcc-4.7)

So I looked to install gcc-4.3 from the repositories but it isn't there. Then I downloaded the gcc-4.3 package separately but when I try to install it I get many conflicting dependencies so installing it is really not an option. I installed gcc-4.4 which is in the repositories and changed the soft link for gcc to link to the gcc-4.4 version but I get the same message above

The compiler used to compile the kernel (gcc-4.3) does not exactly match the current compiler (gcc-4.4)

So the question is, is there a way that I can install the driver successfully without relying on the gcc-4.3?

Comment: You could compile the kernel with gcc-4.7.
I'm quite surprised though that this isn't the case already.

Comment: I ended up installing a more recent kernel. The problem with Debian is that it uses an old kernel. The 3.2 kernel I installed was compiled with gcc-4.6 so that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I installed a 3.2 kernel which was compiled with gcc-4.6 and that worked for me. You could also compile the old kernel using gcc-4.7 although I tried it and had some errors. The problem is that Debian uses a very old kernel so it was compiled with gcc-4.3.